# Limit of $(3x-7)/\sqrt{x^2+5}$ at negative infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

How to find $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}⁡\frac{3x-7}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}$?

I tried with

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}⁡\frac{3x-7}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+5}}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}$$

but not working please any assist will appreciate

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+5}=|x|\sqrt{1+{5\over x^2}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Setting $-x=t\gt 0$ gives us$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{3x-7}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}&=\lim_{t\to \color{red}{+}\infty}\frac{3(-t)-7}{\sqrt{(-t)^2+5}}\\&=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{-3-\frac 7t}{\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{t^2}}}\\&=\frac{-3}{\sqrt 1}\\&=-3.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{3x-7}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{3x-7}{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x^2}}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{3x-7}{|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x^2}}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{3x-7}{-x\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x^2}}}$

$\displaystyle=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{3-\frac{7}{x}}{-\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x^2}}}=\frac{3}{-1}=-3.$

---

Alternate solution:

Since $3x-7<0$ for $x<0$,

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{3x-7}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{-\sqrt{(3x-7)^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}-\frac{\sqrt{9x^2-42x+49}}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}$

$\displaystyle=\lim_{x\to-\infty}-\sqrt{\frac{9x^2-42x+49}{x^2+5}}=-\sqrt{9}=-3.$

Answer (score 0):

Set $-\dfrac1x=h$ to get $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{3x-7}{\sqrt{x^2+5}}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{3/(-h)-7}{\sqrt{1/h^2+5}}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{(-3+7h)|h|}{h\sqrt{1+5h^2}}$$

As $h\to0^+,h>0,|h|=+h,$ cancel out $h$